# Inserting multiple values into list Python/Battleship

Tags: python-3.x

This is the first time I have posted a question, so bear with me if I post anything wrong.

I am creating a Battleship game in Python and got stuck on a particular part of my code. I've managed to add ships of size 1 but not larger sizes. I have used a 2D list for the 10x10 grid/board and a dictionary to hold the ships and their sizes. How to fix? Here is my code so far:

```
def comp_place_ship(comp_board):
    ships = {"A": 4, "B": 3, "C": 2, "S": 2, "D": 1}
    for i, j in ships.items():
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        y = random.randint(0,9)
        place = x,y
        if place != 0:
            print(place)
            comp_board[x][y] = i
            comp_board[x+j][y] = i #THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
            print('The computer has placed ship: ', i)

comp_place_ship(comp_board)
print("--------------------------------------------")
print("--------------------------------------------")
print_comp_board(comp_board)
```

Edit: Might help to show you the output so you know what I mean: [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAxGW.png)

I would also like the marked area to be "A" and not 0.

Comment: Is it throwing an error? It looks like it'll throw an index out of bounds whenever `x+j > 9`. You need to make sure that this doesn't happen. It also appears that all of your ships will be placed in the same orientation, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, `place != 0` will never be `False` (in other words, `place` will never be `0`)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It is not throwing an error yet but the list/board is not how I would like it to be. It does not insert for ex. 4 "A" vertically in a row but A,0,0,A.(If that makes any sense) Edited the question to show the output. I have not added the code for the orientation yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got:

```
from pprint import pprint
import random

comp_board = []*10
for i in xrange(10):
    comp_board.append(['0']*10)

def comp_place_ship(comp_board):
    ships = {"A": 4, "B": 3, "C": 2, "S": 2, "D": 1}
    for i, j in ships.items():
        x = random.randint(0,9-j) # fix the index error
        y = random.randint(0,9)
        place = x,y
        print(place)
        for k in range(j): # you alter a variable number of cells based on the length of the ship
            comp_board[x][y] = i
            comp_board[x+k][y] = i 
            print('The computer has placed ship: ', i)

comp_place_ship(comp_board)
pprint(comp_board)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much @dashiell ! This is exactly what I needed to understand how to do the rest. What kind of a module is pprint by the way? Is it needed or is print enough? This is for a school project and I need to justify the use of the different modules, you see  :)

Comment: pprint is a really nice function that makes printing lists and dictionaries a lot nicer. I was only using it because I didn't have your `print_comp_board` function

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up :) Forgot to add the print_comp_board function. By the way, do you have an idea for how to avoid overlapping the ships? I've tried an if statement like so: if comp_board[x+k][y] == '0' (standard output for empty cell). But that did not work. Sometimes they overlap and sometimes not.

Comment: Rather than just setting `x` and `y`, you could set them, check whether or not that will result in an overlap, and keep randomly picking `x` and `y` until everything works out. You could also keep list of acceptable coordinates for starting positions for each ship, and update those as you place ships on the board. Then pick randomly from that rather than picking a random `x,y`